# JavaFX draw a line from 2 positions using a button

Tags: java, javafx

I want to press a button then press 2 positions and a line will be drawn linking those 2 positions.
I know I need a button handler then to get position of first 2 clicks but how to do that ?

Actually I didnt try much because I didnt know what to try so any insight or code will be helpful.
ps: The question is answered.

Comment: Have a variable representing how many points have been chosen, and set it to zero when the button is pressed. Have variables representing the coordinates of the endpoints of the line. Register a mouse listener on the component where you are going to draw the line. In that mouse listener, if no points have been chosen, save the first point and set the "points chosen" counter to 1. If one point has been chosen, save the second point and draw the line. Try it, create and post a [mre] if there is a specific thing you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `ToggleButton`. That way, your app can have different modes.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    double lineStartX;
    double lineStartY;
    double lineEndX;
    double lineEndY;
    boolean hasFirstPoint = false;
        
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        ToggleButton tbDrawLine = new ToggleButton("Draw Line Mode");
        tbDrawLine.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
            if(t1)
            {
                hasFirstPoint = false;
            }
        });

        Pane paneDrawArea = new Pane();
        paneDrawArea.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
        VBox.setVgrow(paneDrawArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
        
        paneDrawArea.setOnMouseClicked(mouseClickedEvent -> {
            System.out.println("Here! Selected: " + tbDrawLine.isSelected());
            
            if(tbDrawLine.isSelected())
            {
                if(!hasFirstPoint)
                {
                    lineStartX = mouseClickedEvent.getX();
                    lineStartY = mouseClickedEvent.getY();
                    hasFirstPoint = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lineEndX = mouseClickedEvent.getX();
                    lineEndY = mouseClickedEvent.getY();
                    Line line = new Line(lineStartX, lineStartY, lineEndX, lineEndY);
                    paneDrawArea.getChildren().add(line);
                    hasFirstPoint = false;
                }
            }
        });
        
        
        VBox vbRoot = new VBox(tbDrawLine, paneDrawArea);
        var scene = new Scene(vbRoot, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably also a good idea to reset `hasFirstPoint` on `tbDrawLine` is toggled.

Comment: @jewelsea, good one. I did not think of that.

Comment: Code updated based on the advice above!